# Open firefox on top of everything with PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell

I´m running two scripts.

```
. C:\path/Set-Window.ps1
Start-Process -FilePath 'C:/Program Files/Mozilla Firefox/firefox.exe' -ArgumentList https://stackoverflow.com
Start-Sleep -Seconds 0
Set-Window -ProcessName firefox -x 194 -y 18 -Width 1180 -Height 715 -Passthru
```

With  Set-Window.ps1 being:

```
Function Set-Window {
    <#
        .SYNOPSIS
            Sets the window size (height,width) and coordinates (x,y) of
            a process window.

        .DESCRIPTION
            Sets the window size (height,width) and coordinates (x,y) of
            a process window.

        .PARAMETER ProcessName
            Name of the process to determine the window characteristics

        .PARAMETER X
            Set the position of the window in pixels from the top.

        .PARAMETER Y
            Set the position of the window in pixels from the left.

        .PARAMETER Width
            Set the width of the window.

        .PARAMETER Height
            Set the height of the window.

        .PARAMETER Passthru
            Display the output object of the window.

        .NOTES
            Name: Set-Window
            Author: Boe Prox
            Version History
                1.0//Boe Prox - 11/24/2015
                    - Initial build
                1.1//JosefZ (https://superuser.com/users/376602/josefz) - 19.05.2018
                    - treats more process instances of supplied process name properly

        .OUTPUT
            System.Automation.WindowInfo

        .EXAMPLE
            Get-Process powershell | Set-Window -X 2040 -Y 142 -Passthru

            ProcessName Size     TopLeft  BottomRight
            ----------- ----     -------  -----------
            powershell  1262,642 2040,142 3302,784   

            Description
            -----------
            Set the coordinates on the window for the process PowerShell.exe

    #>
    [OutputType('System.Automation.WindowInfo')]
    [cmdletbinding()]
    Param (
        [parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$True)]
        $ProcessName,
        [int]$X,
        [int]$Y,
        [int]$Width,
        [int]$Height,
        [switch]$Passthru
    )
    Begin {
        Try{
            [void][Window]
        } Catch {
        Add-Type @"
              using System;
              using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
              public class Window {
                [DllImport("user32.dll")]
                [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
                public static extern bool GetWindowRect(IntPtr hWnd, out RECT lpRect);

                [DllImport("User32.dll")]
                public extern static bool MoveWindow(IntPtr handle, int x, int y, int width, int height, bool redraw);
              }
              public struct RECT
              {
                public int Left;        // x position of upper-left corner
                public int Top;         // y position of upper-left corner
                public int Right;       // x position of lower-right corner
                public int Bottom;      // y position of lower-right corner
              }
"@
        }
    }
    Process {
        $Rectangle = New-Object RECT
        $Handles = (Get-Process -Name $ProcessName).MainWindowHandle   ### 1.1//JosefZ
        foreach ( $Handle in $Handles ) {                              ### 1.1//JosefZ
            if ( $Handle -eq [System.IntPtr]::Zero ) { Continue }      ### 1.1//JosefZ
            $Return = [Window]::GetWindowRect($Handle,[ref]$Rectangle)
            If (-NOT $PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('Width')) {            
                $Width = $Rectangle.Right - $Rectangle.Left            
            }
            If (-NOT $PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('Height')) {
                $Height = $Rectangle.Bottom - $Rectangle.Top
            }
            If ($Return) {
                $Return = [Window]::MoveWindow($Handle, $x, $y, $Width, $Height,$True)
            }
            If ($PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('Passthru')) {
                $Rectangle = New-Object RECT
                $Return = [Window]::GetWindowRect($Handle,[ref]$Rectangle)
                If ($Return) {
                    $Height = $Rectangle.Bottom - $Rectangle.Top
                    $Width = $Rectangle.Right - $Rectangle.Left
                    $Size = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.Size -ArgumentList $Width, $Height
                    $TopLeft = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.Coordinates -ArgumentList $Rectangle.Left, $Rectangle.Top
                    $BottomRight = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.Coordinates -ArgumentList $Rectangle.Right, $Rectangle.Bottom
                    If ($Rectangle.Top -lt 0 -AND $Rectangle.LEft -lt 0) {
                        Write-Warning "Window is minimized! Coordinates will not be accurate."
                    }
                    $Object = [pscustomobject]@{
                        ProcessName = $ProcessName
                        Size = $Size
                        TopLeft = $TopLeft
                        BottomRight = $BottomRight
                    }
                    $Object.PSTypeNames.insert(0,'System.Automation.WindowInfo')
                    $Object            
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

All of this to open firefox in a specific position on screen. But I also want it to open on top of all the other windows that I have at the moment of execution.

What can I add to the scripts to make this work?

Comment: This happens by default, because starting a new process, especially an .exe is always the active window. If that is not happening for you, then that sounds very odd. What is your goal / use case for this kind of thing, since you are saying you are in a full desktop interactive session, vs just starting FF directly?

Answer (score 0):

Issue an `AppActivate` command after your other commands.

```
(New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell).AppActivate((Get-Process firefox).MainWindowTitle)
```

[Source](https://community.idera.com/database-tools/powershell/powertips/b/tips/posts/bringing-window-in-the-foreground)